# Is there a way in PostgreSQL to find all views that are using foreign data wrappers?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I'm working on a Postgres database project that was not documented at all and one of the major issue is accounting for dependency on foreign datawrappers. I am able to query for all foreign data wrappers in postgres SQL but I don't know how to associate them with views using them.
I did a schema dump using pg_dump and tried to do control find where the wrappers were used but there are too many of them. Is there a tool that can use the schema dump and make sense of it or is there another way to get this dependency information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  pg_rewrite.ev_class::regclass AS view,
  pg_class.oid::regclass AS fdw
FROM pg_depend
JOIN pg_rewrite ON pg_rewrite.oid = objid
JOIN pg_class ON pg_class.oid = refobjid
WHERE pg_class.relkind = 'f'
```

Comment: Thanks Nick this helps a lot! Is there a way to find views that use other views as well using DML?

Comment: @codeBarer: Should be the same query, but with `relkind = 'v'` instead of `relkind = 'f'`